# Help with making a trigger Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have the following two tables:

TABLE 1:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                       | Type                                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| patient_id                  | bigint(20)                           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| patient_wpid                | int(11)                              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| age_at_visit                | int(11)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex                         | enum('male','female')                | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

TABLE 2

```
+-------------------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type                       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| patient_id              | bigint(20)                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| patient_wpid            | int(11)                    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| weight                  | text                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creatinine              | text                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| eGFR                    | varchar(100)               | YES  |     | N/A     |                |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I need to do is, after an insert on Table 2, perform the following:

1. Select the `age_at_visit` and `sex` values from Table 1, for the given `patient_id` and `patient_wpid` (these fields have same values on both Table 1 and Table 2 and Table 1 has been filled BEFORE Table 2)
2. Use the inserted values of `weight` and `creatinine` in Table 2 and calculate a formula, in order to produce, and consecutively store, a value for the `eGFR` column of Table 2.
   The formula is the following:

   eGFR = 175 × (creatinine)^(-1.154) × (age)^(-0.203) × (0.742 if female)

So, what I wrote (and produced quite a few errors since it is my very first attempt with Triggers) is the following:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER calcEGFR AFTER INSERT ON Table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT age_at_visit, sex FROM Table1 WHERE (Table1.patient_wpid = Table2.patient_wpid AND Table1.patient_id = Table2.patient_id)
    SET @creatinine_power := SELECT POWER(creatinine,-1.154);
    SET @age_power := SELECT POWER(Table1.age_at_visit,-0.203);
    IF Table1.sex = 'female' THEN
        SET @sex_addition := 0.742
    END IF;
    IF Table1.sex = 'male' THEN
        SET @sex_addition := 1
    END IF; 

    SET @eGFR_value := (175 * @creatinine_power * @age_power * @sex_addition)
    UPDATE Table2 SET eGFR = @eGFR_value;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Can you please help me correct this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit

What you want has to be a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

The weight i couldn't find in your trigger

Because every variable has to come from somewhere you can define them, get them from the new row, or by a selectl.

You can't access them by writing tabl1.abc or table2.xyz

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS calcEGFR;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER calcEGFR BEFORE INSERT ON Table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE _age_at_visit INTEGER;
DECLARE _sex VARCHAR(10);
    SELECT age_at_visit, sex INTO _age_at_visit, _sex FROM Table1 WHERE (Table1.patient_wpid = NEW.patient_wpid AND Table1.patient_id = NEW.patient_id);
    SET @creatinine_power := POWER(NEW.creatinine,-1.154);
    SET @age_power :=  POWER(_age_at_visit,-0.203);
    IF _sex = 'female' THEN
        SET @sex_addition := 0.742;
    END IF;
    IF _sex = 'male' THEN
        SET @sex_addition := 1;
    END IF; 

    SET @eGFR_value := (175 * @creatinine_power * @age_power * @sex_addition);
    SET NEW.eGFR = @eGFR_value;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Many thanks nbk! You are right, the "weight" I actually do not need, not sure why I put it there. I have a question: can you please tell me what the NEW means and why I need that? Is it a temporary table? Because, I don't understand how the eGFR_value will be inserted into Table2, as needed. Sorry if this is a newbie question, but this is actually my first attempt into making triggers. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it and I get "ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: _age_at_visit"...

Comment: Ok io replicateed your tables to see, if i can resilve all issues and it does give any error message but calcutlate a egfr

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that it is doing what I need it!